# Spring boot taglibs

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot, jsp-tags

I am using Spring boot.

I have a JSP page with the following tag libs:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>  
<%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%>
```

When loading my jsp page, I get the following error:

```
The absolute uri: http://www.springframework.org/security/tags cannot be resolved in either web.xml or the jar files deployed with this application
```

These are my POM dependencies:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: The tld for `http://www.springframework.org/tags/form` is in the `spring-webmvc` jarfile; open your pom dependencies to check if it is pulled in by `spring-boot-starter-web` (i am using spring-boot 1.2.2-SNAPSHOT and it works thanks to that transitive dependency)

Comment: So the question here is whether `spring-boot-starter-security` automatically provisions the `spring-security-taglibs` dependencies too. It appears that it does NOT - they need to be added explicitly as a separate POM dependency entry - in which case is it safe to declare without specifying any version? (`spring-boot-starter-security` is presumably handling the versioning for the core spring security lib etc)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I added following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now it works.

Comment: How does the versioning work in this situation? Get error:  'dependencies.dependency.version' for org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:jar is missing.

Answer (score 6):

Add the following dependency

```
For : <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%> :  

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>


For : <%@ taglib prefix="sec" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags"%> :

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-taglibs</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Gradle users with Tomcat Plugin**

If you are getting this error even if you have your dependency declared in `gradle.build`

```
runtime "org.springframework.security:spring-security-taglibs:${springSecurityVersion}"
```

And you are using the Tomcat plugin:

```
apply plugin: 'com.bmuschko.tomcat'
```

Then you MUST run the gradle task`tomcatRunWar` instead of `tomcatRun`, so that the library is included in your servlet container.

Comment: With Tomcat 7 it is OK but starting from version 8 there is that problem. Thanks for that tip.

Answer (score 0):

Adding taglib library along with security help me to resolve this problem :

compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security:1.5.22.RELEASE'

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework.security', name: 'spring-security-taglibs', version: '4.2.11.RELEASE'
```